# Как упростить выражение? добавить в датафрейм с перезаписью наименований столбцов

Tags: python

Был датафрейм с такими столбцами:

```
data = df[['lat', 'long', 'year', 'odometer/price', 'desc_len', 'model_in_desc', 'model_len', 'model_word_count']]
```

Надо добавить его в исходный (после преобразований данных), переименовав столбцы с общим окончанием _std:

```
df[['lat_std', 'long_std', 'year_std', 'odometer/price_std', 'desc_len_std', 'model_in_desc_std', 'model_len_std', 'model_word_count_std']] = std_scaled
```

Подскажите, как проще это написать?

Comment: Вы, кстати, так  и не приняли ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос. Вас не устроил ни один ответ? Если так - поясните в том вопросе, что вас не устроило. Если какой-то ответ вас устроил, его следует принять.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = [f"{x}_std" for x in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный [метод](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) для этого:

```
data = data.add_suffix('_std', axis=1)
```

Comment: Специальный метод это хорошо